# How to reload clients on URLs other than ROOT_URL onMigrate in meteor?

Tags: meteor

So i realized only clients that have the same ROOT_URL as specified on the server are reloaded on migrations. is there any way to reload them all??

Comment: Meteor features hot code reload, which identifies any code changes on the server and asks the browser to reload.

Comment: Could you describe your apps structure, why would clients have different ROOT_URLs? All of them are supposed to reload even if they don't match, unless one of them doesn't actually connect via DDP and keeps retrying in the first place

Comment: I guess the ROOT_URL is in fact the same, but I'm using multiple subdomains to display my site. Only the subdomain which is the same url as the ROOT_URL reloads.